# Get checked value in edit blade Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

im trying to get selected checkbox in edit blade. but nothing work.

[image]

Here is my code, maybe someone could tell me where i miss

```
<label>Permasalahan</label>
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                  @foreach ($problems as $problem)
                                  <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="" name="problem_id[]" {{ $problem->id == 'problem_id' ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="" name="problem_id[]" value="{{ $problem->id }}">
                                    <label class="fs-6 fw-light">{{ $problem->name }}</label>
                                  </div>
                                  @endforeach
                                </div>
                              </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have two checkboxes for each problem ? and why are you comparing $problem->id to the string 'problem_id' ?

Comment: oh, the one is for testing. i dont know how to do that correctly, thats why

Comment: Try the in_array function to check the value of a check box in it. See the below reference.

{{ in_array($problem->id, "problem_id") ? "checked" : "" }}